# Listing files to generate dynamic components with list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, internationalization, create-react-app

I want a scalable solution, using React, to list some pages and automatically using the last one as my main page.

I have my 'legals mention' page, which will be regularly updated with new content.

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
function Legals() {
    const { t } = useTranslation('common');
  return (
<div>
    <h1>Legals</h1>
    <span>Version 2.1 - 4th revision</span>
    <span>· Effective September 30, 2020</span>
    <button>Archived versions</button>
    {...}<Content>{...}
</div>
)}

export default Legals;
```

So this is supposed to display the most recent version, and contains a button with a list to older versions.

I was thinking of using i18n and check in a folder for the last version, is it the best way to do it?
How to accomplish it, at least in pseudocode?

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you are trying to achieve? And if possible please share code snippets or samples.

Comment: Tried to be clearer in my edit. Ask if anything seems too blurry.